# How can I set the value of a variable being passed to a role based on ansible_facts?

Tags: ansible

I'm using [geerlingguy's NTP role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-ntp) to set up NTP client software on a collection of hosts. I'd like to point this play at a hostgroup and have Ansible figure out on the fly whether or not each machine is a VM (an important thing to note here is that all of our VMs are running on KVM hypervisors). If the host is a VM, `ntp_tinker_panic` should be set to `true`. Otherwise, it should be set to `false`. Here's the play I wrote:

```
- name: Set up NTP or chronyd on Linux hosts
  hosts: ntp
  tasks:
    - name: Print the value of ntp_tinker_panic
      debug:
        var: ntp_tinker_panic
    - name: Ensure time sync software is installed and configured
      include_role:
        name: geerlingguy.ntp
  vars:
    ntp_enabled: true
    ntp_manage_config: true
    ntp_timezone: America/New_York
    ntp_servers:
      - "time.google.com"
    ntp_tinker_panic: "{{ ansible_facts['ansible_product_name'] == 'KVM' }}"
  tags:
    - ntp
```

However, even though the play executes without errors, the debug message states that `ntp_tinker_panic` is not defined:

```
TASK [Print the value of ntp_tinker_panic] *****************************************************************************
ok: [hostname] => {
    "ntp_tinker_panic": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Is there a way for me to set the value of that variable on a per-host basis as the play is running instead of defining separate hostgroups for VMs and physical hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would like to set the value of `ntp_tinker_panic` conditionally. Whereas your definition of the variable in the `vars` section is not going to set it to `true`. And it does not take into consideration each host of the `ntp` group.

You should use `set_fact` task in the play to set this variable to true if `ansible_product_name` matches `KVM` for that host.

Example:

```yaml
# ntp_tinker_panic not specified here in vars as it is target specific
  vars:
    ntp_enabled: true
    ntp_manage_config: true
    ntp_timezone: America/New_York
    ntp_servers:
      - "time.google.com"

  tasks:
    - name: Set ntp_tinker_panic for KVM
      set_fact:
        ntp_tinker_panic: true
      when: ansible_product_name == "KVM"
    - name: Print the value of ntp_tinker_panic
      debug:
        var: ntp_tinker_panic
```